# django how to write queryset which matches NESTED SELECT

Tags: django, orm, django-models

I need to get queryset, which is similar to this in SQL:

```
select * from kraj
where kraj_id in (select kraj_id from klient_kraj where klient_id = 1)
```

As you can see, I work with `klient_kraj` model, which is filtered and 1 column is returned `kraj_id`, which is then used for another filtering.

I wasn't able to find way, how to obtain this queryset using ORM.

Thanks